# Html Css: Hover Property not Working on Google Icon

Tags: html, css, svg, asp.net-core-mvc, google-material-icons

How come this hover property is not working? It is supposed to be hidden, however when I click over the icon area, it is supposed to be visible. This is stuck at hidden.

```
.testdelete {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Material Icons;
    visibility: hidden;
}


.testdelete:hover .testdelete {
    visibility: visible;
}

.testdelete:not(hover) .testdelete {
    visibility: hidden;
}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div class="testdelete">delete</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot hover over a hidden element. One solution is to nest the element inside another container.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<style type="text/css">

.testdelete .insideElement{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Material Icons;
 visibility: hidden;
}

.testdelete:hover .insideElement {
 visibility: visible;
}

.testdelete:not(hover) .insideElement {
 visibility: hidden;    
}

</style>

<html> 
<head>
<div class="testdelete">
<div class="insideElement">delete</div>
</div>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

One way around the `visibility` issue is to use `opacity` instead.

```css
.testdelete {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Material Icons;
  opacity: 0;
}

.testdelete:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div class="testdelete">delete</div>
```